# Open Source Elasticsearch synonym dictionaries / thesaurus especially for place names?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for some kind of dictionary/thesaurus that I can use for Elasticsearch to define synonyms specifically for place names. I.e.

```
United States,United States of America, US => USA,
Kingdom of Saudi Arabia, Saudi Arabia, => KSA
...
```